woocomerce надпись Представлено 10 товаров
В woocomerce  есть надпись по умолчание на странице товаров
"Представлено 10 товаров", можно ее изменить?


Все "надписи" - это переводы. Соответственно их можно менять в лангпаке.
Наиболее просто и правильно это сделать с помощью Loco translate, создав кастомный лангпак из имеющегося.
