Как изменить текст в Woocommerce Subscriptions?
Есть сайт с подписками https://chocopay.ru/.
По умолчанию, плагин Woocommerce Subscriptions оформляет товар так:

Как сделать, чтобы вместо слова "каждые" был "/" как в первом товаре? В каком файле это можно отредактировать?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1581628/woocomerce-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-10-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2/1581636#1581636
